# Document level event handling with having inner events

Tags: html, jquery, event-handling, document, jquery-events

I want to bind event on document level
means want to say that:

I want to get first event as  on document level
then on outerDiv
then on innerSpan
then on inner elements

If am adding clicks on inner Html and google search to but not get proper solution.

If their is First in First out I had added first event for document to but still fires innerHTMl events first.

i want to get the document level first event whenever user clicks on document first function call the document function

Comment: It would be more helpful in understanding the question with an example or a extract from your code.

Comment: my html look like    
<div id=parent>
    <div id=child>
     </div>
 </div>

whenever i had added event on child div like
$("#child").click(function(){alert("b")});

and same event on document 

$(document).on("click",function(){ alert("a") })

so i need to happen alert a 
but when i am clicking on child then first alert is b then a comes

Comment: i had google it and got better solution for it  in javascript
url is   https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing